# Set up Multi-Module Maven Project with SpringBoot and React Sub-Modules

Tags: spring-boot, maven, monorepo, multi-module

I am trying to setup a monorepo containing both a SpringBoot and a React Application. Currently, my module structure looks like the following:

```
root
+-- backend
|   +-- pom.xml
+-- frontend
|   +-- pom.xml
+-- pom.xml
```

Parent pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>multi-module-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>frontend</module>
        <module>backend</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

frontend/pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>multi-module-demo</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

and backend/pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

While looking at the `backend/pom.xml`, I have the issue that the parent is not my parent pom, but the SpringBoot pom. This way however, I could technically not manage e.g. the version of the Project. Because currently the build output is

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] multi-module-demo 1.0-SNAPSHOT ..................... SUCCESS [  0.150 s]
[INFO] frontend 1.0-SNAPSHOT .............................. SUCCESS [  0.784 s]
[INFO] backend 3.0.2 ...................................... SUCCESS [  4.102 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

where you can see that the versions are not matching of each artifact.

My question is, how do I need to adapt the backend pom to match the frontend pom?

Comment: Based on such setup you can make general configuraiton like defining which jdk versions via `<maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>` and defining the encoding in your parent instead of repeating that in each module...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further digging, here's what I need to add to my parent pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem similar to yours, same pom structure migrating a Java ee project with ant to springboot java multimodule.

The pom principal is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.events-schedule.tecnoprintcb</groupId>
    <artifactId>events-schedule</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>events-schedule-ejb</module>
        <module>events-schedule-war</module>
    </modules>
    <name>events-schedule</name>
    <description>Schedule Event System for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
<!-- Dependencia al proyecto web empaquetado como .jar -->
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependencias de Thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!-- Dependencias de Spring Boot -->
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>          <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependencia para CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.SP1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependencia para EJB (Enterprise JavaBeans) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependencias de JavaMail API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
  <excludes>
 <exclude>                         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
 </exclude>
</excludes>
  <modules>
  <ejbModule>
                                <groupId>com.events-schedule.tecnoprintcb</groupId>
                            
<artifactId>events-schedule-ejb</artifactId>
  </ejbModule>
 <webModule>
                                <groupId>com.events-schedule.tecnoprintcb</groupId>
                                <artifactId>events-schedule-war</artifactId>
                                <contextRoot>/</contextRoot>
 </webModule>
   </modules>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
 </plugins>
 </build>
    </project>
```

Ejb pom:

```
       <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.events-schedule.tecnoprintcb</groupId>
        <artifactId>events-schedule-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <packaging>ejb</packaging>
        <name>events-schedule-ejb-1.0</name>
        
        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <maven.ejb.version>3.2</maven.ejb.version>
            <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <jakartaee>8.0</jakartaee>
        </properties>
        
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.ejb.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                                <silent>true</silent>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                                        <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                                        <type>jar</type>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

War pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.events-schedule.tecnoprintcb</groupId>
<artifactId>events-schedule-ejb</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
 <name>events-schedule-ejb-1.0</name>
<properties>
                <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
                <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
                <maven.ejb.version>3.2</maven.ejb.version>
                <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
<version>${jakartaee}</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <build>
 <plugins>
 <plugin>                       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.ejb.version}</version>
<configuration>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                            <compilerArguments>
                                <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                            </compilerArguments>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3</version>
<configuration>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</configuration>
</plugin>
  ññ<plugin>                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
      <executions>
       <execution>                          <phase>validate</phase>
     <goals>                              <goal>copy</goal>
     </goals>
    <configuration>                              <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                                    <silent>true</silent>
                                    <artifactItems>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                                            <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                                            <type>jar</type>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                    </artifactItems>
                                </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
      </plugin>
      </plugins>
      </build>
        </project>
```

The error is in war package not detect the inject import classes of ejb.